# Styling angular web components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, web-component

While Angular has native support for [Web components](https://www.webcomponents.org/specs), it is unclear to me how to style a web component with SCSS without leaking the styles on the hosting page.

Obviously, if a component has its rules defined in its .scss files, those rules apply only to that component.

```
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |                                                                       |
  |                                                                       |
  |                                                                       |
  |   +----------------------------------------------------------------+  |
  |   |                                                                |  |
  |   |                                                                |  |
  |   |                        Web component                           |  |
  |   |                                                                |  |
  |   |                                                                |  |
  |   | +---------------------------+  +-----------------------------+ |  |
  |   | |                           |  |                             | |  |
  |   | |                           |  |                             | |  |
  |   | |      Sub component A      |  |       Sub component B       | |  |
  |   | |                           |  |                             | |  |
  |   | |                           |  |                             | |  |
  |   | +---------------------------+  +-----------------------------+ |  |
  |   +----------------------------------------------------------------+  |
  |                                                                       |
  |                                                                       |
  |                           Web page                                    |
  |                                                                       |
  |                                                                       |
  |                                                                       |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In a typical example, let's say that I have a web page with a custom component created with @angular/elements.

Normally, in an Angular app, I would define my styles in /src/styles.scss in which I would import all my external frameworks-related styles and other global definitions which would result, after a build, in a CSS file that contains everything.

However, if I link this file to the hosting page, all the styles contained there would be valid for the entire page. So a

```
p {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Would make all `<p>` tags be red with a black background.

However, due to the nature of angular encapsulation, there is nowhere I can put this style rule in the angular to make it valid from application bootstrap to every component under it. Or is there?

If I put my style in the app.component.scss or MyCustomElement.component.scss the rule is valid just in that component, and this is an obvious design mechanism in Angular.

I found [this article](https://dev.to/m4thieulavoie/how-i-managed-to-use-scss-inside-web-components-3lk9) talking about transforming the SCSS file in a js import and that seems a proper solution, however, I wasn't able to port it to an angular project with ease but will try again.

Any answer but also suggestion/link to the official documentation on how this could be achieved would be much appreciated

[Edit] To clarify my question: I would like to have a space on an Angular Generated Web component in order to put some styles global to the component but not to the page who’s hosting it. Creative methods such as injecting a scss converted to javascript also could be interesting. I just didn’t find one that was practical enough to use it in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Stylings put in the `src/styles.scss` will be applicable for all components. In fact, all files you put onder the `styles` array in your `angular.json` will be applicable for all components.

However, if you specifically want to override stylings of a component you can use the `::ng-deep` selector before your stylings.

Comment: thanks @Ruben . But will styles rulesets put in src/styles.scss which will generate a styles.css which should be linked in the hosting page be limited to the webcomponent or will they "leak" into the hosting page? that is my problem

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say. Could you rephrase?

Comment: basically, the question is: the styles which are included in the styles array are put in a styles.css file which will include all global styles. Every style that is not shadowed in a component, so every style which is “global” to my web component, if linked in a css link for the hosting page will leak into the page.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I fully understand, sorry. However, from what I understand you're referring to what happens if you link the styles stylesheet (or any other stylesheet from the styles array) specifically into a component? It would apply the styles, but you don't need to import the stylesheet since the styles are already applied because its global. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking. I'm sorry if this doesn't help you.

Comment: I'm just realizing how incredibly bad I am in explaining this particular question. Let's say you want all `p` in your component, to be red. You would define `p{color:red}` in your styles.scss in angular, and that would work in an application. But then, when you export your styles.css file, if you include it in the page that hosts your web component based on angular, every `p` in the hosting page becomes red. Which is not what you would want.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand it, but styling from components will never be applied in the parent component. The styling is locked to the component self. However, you can override subcomponents with `::ng-deep` selector

Comment: You're correct, but my issue is not related to angular itself, but to general styles  linked in the production-generated "styles.css" which, if linked in a page which hosts an angular "webcomponent" (not application) would leak to the page if not selector specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a correct solution. But, you can try something like creating a separate "style-standalone.scss" file for your web-component and add it in to the configurations of that web-component defined on angular.json.

```
"web-component": {
          "styles": [
            "src/styles-standalone.scss"
          ],
          "outputPath": "dist/your-project/web-component",
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.web-components.ts"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/app/app.module.ts",
              "with": "src/app/app.module.webcomponent.el.ts"
            }
          ],
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "1mb",
              "maximumError": "2mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "10kb",
              "maximumError": "20kb"
            }
          ],
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "optimization": true,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
```